# Seam Quartz Dispatcher not firing on seconds and minutes field for a given cron expression

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler, seam, cronexpression

I have a Quartz job that is to fire for a certain time repeatedly. Unfortunately it does not fire for some unknown reasons.

Here is my cron expression :

```
0/5 0 0 * * ?
```

So basically the job should be fired every 5 seconds. This is the part which does not work.

Now the wierd thing is when I changed the cron expression to

```
0 0 0/1 * * ?
```

which fire the job at every 1 hour. The job is fired and I can see that the method is being invoked on the Java side.

I have tried also on the minute field eg. `0 0/5 0 * * ?` for every 5 minutes but it does not fire either.

I don't know what is the behavior is that the other two expression are not firing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is also my *seam.quartz.properties* file

```
Configure Main Scheduler Properties

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName QuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy false

Configure ThreadPool

org.quartz.threadPool.class org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount 10

Configure JobStore

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

I am using Jboss 5.1.0, Seam 2.2 and Quartz 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0/5 0 0 * * ?
```

The above cron expression will schedule the job to trigger every 5 seconds during *minute* `0` and *hour* `0` daily. In other words, the first minute every day, the job will execute 12 times.

I assume you want it to trigger any hour, that is every 5 seconds regardless of the hour.

Replace the two zeros indicating *minute* and *hour* with the `*` wildcard. Also, you don't need `?` which means *no specific value*. The below expression will schedule the timer every 5 seconds, regardless of which *hour* or *minute* it is:

```
0/5 * * * * *
```

The reason why `0 0 0/1 * * ?` is "working" is because you undertand the expression correctly, which you didn't with the ones that were "not working". Basically it means every *1 hour at the start of a new hour (minute 0 and second 0)*.

This documentation is an excellent resource with examples for Quartz 1.X:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger